# Is it possible to make an option in optparse a mandatory?

Tags: python, optparse

Is it possible to make an option in optparse a mandatory?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Check out the answer to this question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407539/)

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't do that, because that's against convention and standard of command line interface. There is a reason, why options can't be made mandatory. Read the `optparse` docs, it is stated there clearly.

Comment: Ok, then why is that `argparse` allows for required options? To quote, `argparse` docs: `Optparse refuses to support these features, preferring purity over practicality.`

Comment: I believe you have answered your own question :-) I am using argparse, because I like positional argument functionality, but I keep to command line standards.

Comment: I understand the point you are trying to make, but there is a difference between 'not possible' and 'should be avoided.'

Comment: Besides the fact that the `optparse` module is deprecated, making an option mandatory seems like an oxymoron...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I posted a comment earlier, but given that many other answers say `No, not possible`, here is how to do it:

```
parser = OptionParser(usage='usage: %prog [options] arguments')
parser.add_option('-f', '--file', 
                        dest='filename',
                        help='foo help')
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
if options.filename is None:   # if filename is not given
    parser.error('Filename not given')
```

This makes the `-f` as mandatory.

Using `argparse` is an alternative indeed, but that doesn't mean you can't do this in `optparse` also.

Comment: Okay, this is what I meant by ( - optparse set it to some default like None and check for not None), I think should have provided an example. Thanks. BTW, this is not done by optparse, you are doing it by checking for the option's value in the program.

Comment: Indeed, `optparse` has no role, this is just a way to make an option required.

Answer (score 8):

option is by defeinition optional :-) If you need to make something mandatory, use `argparse` and set a positional argument.

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Comment: You can install argparse separately. http://code.google.com/p/argparse/ Then, when you upgrade python, you can migrate painlessly.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Either you can use `argparse` and or you get the option value from using the optparse module and explicitly check if the optionvalue is defined (like in the optparse set it to some default like None and check for not None) and if it is not defined, call `sys.exit()` asking the users to provide that option.