# Simple argparse example wanted: 1 argument, 3 results

Tags: python, argparse

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) for the [argparse python module](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/argparse/), while excellent I'm sure, is too much for my tiny beginner brain to grasp right now. I don't need to do math on the command line or meddle with formatting lines on the screen or change option characters. All I want to do is *"If arg is A, do this, if B do that, if none of the above show help and quit"*.

Comment: then just check `sys.argv` for the argument you want...

Comment: Ever tried [plac](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac)? It's an easy to use wrapper over argparse with [great documentation](http://plac.googlecode.com/hg/doc/plac.html).

Comment: it's not you. it's argparse. it's trying to take you on a journey to the stars and doesn't care where you were headed.

Comment: Crazy "pythonic" APIs again :/

Comment: Bless you matt wilkie, for standing up for tiny beginner brains everywhere.

Comment: What is badly needed in python is a library supporting a declarative form of argparse/getopts.  Something that will allow a 2-line get all options and loop over file (or stdin if no file is given) similar to perl's `getopts('abc:d:'); while (< >) {...}`  the python equivalent of this simple and widely used construct requires multiple lines of not simple code that has to be repeated in way too many scripts.

Comment: Related: [Why use argparse rather than optparse?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3217673/3345375)

Comment: No, the documentation is RUBBISH. Most Python documentation is.

Comment: Freaking terrible, this argparse documentation is

Comment: You may also try click for CLIs https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/

Comment: It's not just argparse, the intelhex documentation is similar garbage. I don't even bother reading it and just read the code instead.

Answer (score 311, accepted):

My understanding of the original question is two-fold. First, in terms of the simplest possible argparse example, I'm surprised that I haven't seen it here. Of course, to be dead-simple, it's also all overhead with little power, but it might get you started.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("a")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.a == 'magic.name':
    print 'You nailed it!'
```

But this positional argument is now required. If you leave it out when invoking this program, you'll get an error about missing arguments. This leads me to the second part of the original question. Matt Wilkie seems to want a single **optional** argument without a named label (the --option labels). My suggestion would be to modify the code above as follows:

```
...
parser.add_argument("a", nargs='?', default="check_string_for_empty")
...
if args.a == 'check_string_for_empty':
    print 'I can tell that no argument was given and I can deal with that here.'
elif args.a == 'magic.name':
    print 'You nailed it!'
else:
    print args.a
```

There may well be a more elegant solution, but this works and is minimalist.

Comment: After some time reflecting, I conclude this question actually best answers the Q as asked and the predicament I was in at the time. The other excellent answers have garnered more than enough rep to prove their worth and can stand a little competition. :-)

Comment: @badnack: It's whatever you want it to be, whatever 'a' represents. If you expect one argument, a file name for example, it is what was entered as the file name on the command line. You could then do your own processing to determine whether it exists in the filesystem, but that is another Q&A.

Comment: @mightypile could you please tell me when exactly "positional argument" is useful? I added something like this `parser.add_argument('n', nargs='?', default=5)` in my code and when I run `python3 test.py n 3`, I get this error: `usage: test.py [-h] [n]
 test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 3` Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Milan A positional argument would be required at its given position and would not need to be explicitly named when invoked because it's required/expected/positional (ie `test.py 3`). You created a script with a single *optional* argument (and no positional arguments) and as expected, it read "n" as the first argument named "n" (so `args.n == "n"`) and does not know what to do with the "3". See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs)

Comment: @mightypile I see...now I understood. Thank you so much for your time and for replying back :)

Answer (score 470):

Here's the way I do it with `argparse` (with multiple args):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
parser.add_argument('-f','--foo', help='Description for foo argument', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-b','--bar', help='Description for bar argument', required=True)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

`args` will be a dictionary containing the arguments:

```
if args['foo'] == 'Hello':
    # code here

if args['bar'] == 'World':
    # code here
```

In your case simply add only one argument.

Comment: as mentioned in my comment to the other answer, I'd like to keep argparse's automatic help formatting, but there doesn't seem to be an option to have an unamed argument (more likely I just don't understand it when I see it), e.g. one needs to do `foo.py --action install` or `foo.py --action remove` instead of simply `foo.py install`

Comment: @mattwilkie Then you have to define a positional argument like this:
    
`parser.add_argument('install', help='Install the app')`    
  
  
(Notice you can't define a positional argument with `required=True`)

Comment: @strongMA `parser.parse_args()` is a namespace, my `args` local variable is a dict because `vars(parser.parse_args())` returns a dict and it is perfectly iterable.

Comment: As a noob to argparse, this answer really helped because *I did not know where to find the options after they were passed*.  In other words, I needed to understand how the `args` dict was generated as above.

Comment: What's the point of the `'-f'` and `'-b'`? Why can't you omit this?

Comment: @user2763361 You can omit `-f` and `-b`, it's fine with `--foo` and `--bar` Those are both valid ways to define 'optional' arguments (https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method)

Comment: Use the 'short form' when calling program directly from command line and the 'long form' when you run a program/command within a script. In that case it is more human readable with the long form and thus easier to follow the logic of the code/script.

Comment: Personally I find it cleaner to access arguments as `args.foo` and `args.bar` instead of the dictionary syntax. Either way is fine of course, but args is not actually a dictionary but an `argparse.Namespace` object.

Comment: @DiegoNavarro why is that `args['foo']` works but `args['f']` gives a `KeyError` error? On the other hand, in `add_argument`, if I don't specify a named label (the --option labels) i.e. `parser.add_argument('-f', help='Description for foo argument', required=True)` then I can use `args['f']`. Why? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Milan argparse uses the long argument name as the name in the python code (Because that's more readable usually) unless it does not exist. If it does not exist, it uses the short form.

Answer (score 244):

The `argparse` documentation is reasonably good but leaves out a few useful details which might not be obvious. (@Diego Navarro already mentioned some of this but I'll try to expand on his answer slightly.) Basic usage is as follows:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--my-foo', default='foobar')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--bar-value', default=3.14)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The object you get back from `parse_args()` is a 'Namespace' object: An object whose member variables are named after your command-line arguments.  The `Namespace` object is how you access your arguments and the values associated with them:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
print (args.my_foo)
print (args.bar_value)
```

(Note that `argparse` replaces '-' in your argument names with underscores when naming the variables.)

In many situations you may wish to use arguments simply as flags which take no value. You can add those in argparse like this:

```
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--no-foo', action='store_false')
```

The above will create variables named 'foo' with value True, and 'no_foo' with value False, respectively:

```
if (args.foo):
    print ("foo is true")

if (args.no_foo is False):
    print ("nofoo is false")
```

Note also that you can use the "required" option when adding an argument:

```
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', required=True)
```

That way if you omit this argument at the command line `argparse` will tell you it's missing and stop execution of your script.

Finally, note that it's possible to create a dict structure of your arguments using the `vars` function, if that makes life easier for you.

```
args = parser.parse_args()
argsdict = vars(args)
print (argsdict['my_foo'])
print (argsdict['bar_value'])
```

As you can see, `vars` returns a dict with your argument names as keys and their values as, er, values.

There are lots of other options and things you can do, but this should cover the most essential, common usage scenarios.

Comment: What's the point of the `'-f'` and `'-b'`? Why can't you omit this?

Comment: It's pretty conventional to have both a 'short form' (one dash) and 'long form' (two dashes) version for each runtime option. You will see this, for example, in almost every standard Unix/Linux utility; do a `man cp` or `man ls` and you'll find that many options come in both flavors (e.g. `-f, --force`). There are probably widely varying reasons why people prefer one or the other, but in any case it's pretty standard to make both forms available in your program.

Comment: @DMH Why is that `print(args.my_foo)` works but `print(args.f)` gives an error: `AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'f'`? On the other hand, in `add_argument`, if I don't specify a named label (the --option labels) i.e. `parser.add_argument('-f', default='foobar')` then I can run `print(args.f)`. Why? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 66):

Matt is asking about positional parameters in argparse, and I agree that the Python documentation is lacking on this aspect. There's not a single, complete example in the ~20 odd pages that shows both **parsing and using positional parameters**.

None of the other answers here show a complete example of positional parameters, either, so here's a complete example:

```
# tested with python 2.7.1
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="An argparse example")

parser.add_argument('action', help='The action to take (e.g. install, remove, etc.)')
parser.add_argument('foo-bar', help='Hyphens are cumbersome in positional arguments')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.action == "install":
    print("You asked for installation")
else:
    print("You asked for something other than installation")

# The following do not work:
# print(args.foo-bar)
# print(args.foo_bar)

# But this works:
print(getattr(args, 'foo-bar'))
```

The thing that threw me off is that argparse will convert the named argument "--foo-bar" into "foo_bar", but a positional parameter named "foo-bar" stays as "foo-bar", making it less obvious how to use it in your program.

Notice the two lines near the end of my example -- neither of those will work to get the value of the foo-bar positional param. The first one is obviously wrong (it's an arithmetic expression args.foo minus bar), but the second one doesn't work either:

```
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'foo_bar'
```

If you want to use the `foo-bar` attribute, you must use `getattr`, as seen in the last line of my example. What's crazy is that if you tried to use `dest=foo_bar` to change the property name to something that's easier to access, you'd get a really bizarre error message:

```
ValueError: dest supplied twice for positional argument
```

Here's how the example above runs:

```
$ python test.py
usage: test.py [-h] action foo-bar
test.py: error: too few arguments

$ python test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] action foo-bar

An argparse example

positional arguments:
  action      The action to take (e.g. install, remove, etc.)
  foo-bar     Hyphens are cumbersome in positional arguments

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

$ python test.py install foo
You asked for installation
foo
```

Comment: `nargs='?'` is the incantation for an "optional positional" as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480075/argparse-optional-positional-arguments

Comment: The fact that a positional `foo-bar` is not transformed to `foo_bar` is addressed in http://bugs.python.org/issue15125.

Comment: I think an easier workaround for this bug is to just call the argument "foo_bar" instead of "foo-bar", then `print args.foo_bar` works. Since it is an positional argument you don't have to specify the name when calling the script, so it doesn't matter for the user.

Comment: @luator You're right, it is easy to rename the argument, but the author of the bug report makes a good case that this is still a misfeature because of the unnecessary cognitive load. When using argparse, one must pause and recall the different naming conventions for options and arguments. See http://bugs.python.org/msg164968.

Comment: @mehaase I totally agree that this is a misfeature that should be fixed. I just think renaming the argument is the easier and less confusing workaround than having to use `getattr` (it is also more flexible as it allows you to change an argument from optional to positional without having to change the code that uses the value).

Answer (score 31):

Yet another summary introduction, inspired by [this post](https://martin-thoma.com/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-python/).

```
import argparse

# define functions, classes, etc.

# executes when your script is called from the command-line
if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    #
    # define each option with: parser.add_argument
    #
    args = parser.parse_args() # automatically looks at sys.argv
    #
    # access results with: args.argumentName
    #
```

Arguments are defined with combinations of the following:

```
parser.add_argument( 'name', options... )              # positional argument
parser.add_argument( '-x', options... )                # single-char flag
parser.add_argument( '-x', '--long-name', options... ) # flag with long name
```

---

Common options are:

- [help](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#help): description for this arg when `--help` is used.
- [default](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#default): default value if the arg is omitted.
- [type](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#type): if you expect a `float` or `int` (otherwise is `str`).
- [dest](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#dest): give a different name to a flag (e.g. `'-x', '--long-name', dest='longName'`).
   *Note: by default `--long-name` is accessed with `args.long_name`*
- [action](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#action): for special handling of certain arguments

  - **`store_true, store_false`:** for boolean args 
     `'--foo', action='store_true' => args.foo == True`
  - **`store_const`:** to be used with option `const`
     `'--foo', action='store_const', const=42 => args.foo == 42`
  - **`count`:** for repeated options, as in `./myscript.py -vv` 
     `'-v', action='count' => args.v == 2`
  - **`append`:** for repeated options, as in `./myscript.py --foo 1 --foo 2`
     `'--foo', action='append' => args.foo == ['1', '2']`
- [required](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#required): if a flag is required, or a positional argument is not.
- [nargs](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#nargs): for a flag to capture N args
   `./myscript.py --foo a b  =>  args.foo = ['a', 'b']`
- [choices](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#choices): to restrict possible inputs (specify as list of strings, or ints if `type=int`).

Answer (score 15):

Here's what I came up with in my learning project thanks mainly to @DMH...

Demo code:

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--flag', action='store_true', default=False)  # can 'store_false' for no-xxx flags
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--reqd', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--opt', default='fallback')
    parser.add_argument('arg', nargs='*') # use '+' for 1 or more args (instead of 0 or more)
    parsed = parser.parse_args()
    # NOTE: args with '-' have it replaced with '_'
    print('Result:',  vars(parsed))
    print('parsed.reqd:', parsed.reqd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This may have evolved and is available online: [command-line.py](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn/python/fundamental/command-line.py)

Script to give this code a workout: [command-line-demo.sh](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn/python/fundamental/command-line-demo.sh)

Comment: Finally a argparse example that makes sense

Answer (score 13):

Note the [Argparse Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/argparse.html) in [Python HOWTOs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/index.html).  It starts from most basic examples, like this one:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("square", type=int,
                    help="display a square of a given number")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.square**2)
```

and progresses to less basic ones.

There is an example with predefined choice for an option, like what is asked:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("square", type=int,
                    help="display a square of a given number")
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbosity", type=int, choices=[0, 1, 2],
                    help="increase output verbosity")
args = parser.parse_args()
answer = args.square**2
if args.verbosity == 2:
    print("the square of {} equals {}".format(args.square, answer))
elif args.verbosity == 1:
    print("{}^2 == {}".format(args.square, answer))
else:
    print(answer)
```

Comment: It's nice to see that the docs have been updated. I assure you this wasn't the case when OP posted the question 5 years ago.

Answer (score 13):

code file: `argparseDemo.py`

## Simple: common case

- name(abbr, full), with help

  ```py
  import argparse

  argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  argParser.add_argument("-n", "--name", help="your name")

  args = argParser.parse_args()
  print("args=%s" % args)

  print("args.name=%s" % args.name)
  ```

  - call

    - `python argparseDemo.py -n Crifan`
    - `python argparseDemo.py --name Crifan`
  - output: `args=Namespace(name='Crifan')` and `args.name=Crifan`
- type

  ```py
  argParser.add_argument("-a", "--age", type=int, help="your current age")
  print("type(args.age)=%s" % type(args.age))
  ```

  - call: `python argparseDemo.py --age 30`
  - output: `type(args.age)=<class 'int'>` and `args.age=30`
- required

  ```py
  argParser.add_argument("-a", "--age", required=True, type=int, help="your current age")
  ```

  - call: `python argparseDemo.py`
  - output: error `argparseDemo.py: error: the following arguments are required: -a/--age`
- default

  ```py
  argParser.add_argument("-a", "--age", type=int, default=20, help="your current age. Default is 20")
  ```

  - call: `python argparseDemo.py`
  - output: `args.age=20`
- choices

  ```py
  argParser.add_argument("-f", "--love-fruit", choices=['apple', 'orange', 'banana'], help="your love fruits")
  ```

  - call: `python argparseDemo.py -f apple`
  - output: `args=Namespace(love_fruit='apple')` and `args.love_fruit=apple`
- multi args

  ```py
  argParser.add_argument("-f", "--love-fruit", nargs=2, help="your love fruits")
  ```

  - call: `python argparseDemo.py -f apple orange`
  - output: `args.love_fruit=['apple', 'orange']`

## Detail

### most simple: `-x`

- code:

  ```py
  import argparse

  argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  argParser.add_argument("-a") # most simple -> got args.a, type is `str`
  args = argParser.parse_args()

  print("args.a=%s" % args.a)
  ```
- usage = run in command line

  ```sh
  python argparseDemo.py -a 30
  ```

  - or: `./argparseDemo.py -a 30`

    - makesure `argparseDemo.py` is executable

      - if not, add it: `chmod +x argparseDemo.py`
- output

  ```sh
  args.a=30
  ```
- Note

  - default type is `str`

    - `argParser.add_argument("-a")` == `argParser.add_argument("-a", type=str)`
    - `print("type(args.a)=%s" % type(args.a))` -> `type(args.a)=<class 'str'>`
  - `args` type is `Namespace`

    - `print("type(args)=%s" % type(args))` -> `type(args)=<class 'argparse.Namespace'>`
  - `args` value is `Namespace(a='30')`

    - `print("args=%s" % args)` -> `args=Namespace(a='30')`
    - so we can call/use `args.a`

### parameter name

#### full parameter name: `--xxx`

- code

  ```py
  argParser.add_argument("-a", "--age")
  ```
- usage

  - `python argparseDemo.py -a 30`

    - or: `python argparseDemo.py --age 30`
- get parsed value: `args.age`

  - Note: **NOT** `args.a`, and **NOT exist** `args.a`

#### full parameter name with multiple words: `--xxx-yyy`

- code

  ```py
  argParser.add_argument("-a", "--current-age")
  ```
- get parsed value: args.**current_age**

### add help description: `help`

- code

  ```py
  argParser.add_argument("-a", help="your age") # with help
  ```
- output

  - use `--help` can see description

    ```sh
     python argparseDemo.py --help
    usage: argparseDemo.py [-h] [-a A]

    optional arguments:
    -h, --help  show this help message and exit
    -a A        your age
    ```

### designate parameter type: `type`

- code

  ```py
  argParser.add_argument("-a", type=int) # parsed arg is `int`, not default `str`
  ```
- output

  - `print("type(args.a)=%s" % type(args.a))` -> `type(args.a)=<class 'int'>`
  - `print("args=%s" % args)` -> `args=Namespace(a=30)`

### add default value: `default`

- code

  ```py
  argParser.add_argument("-a", type=int, default=20) # if not pass a, a use default value: 20
  ```
- effect

  - usage: `python argparseDemo.py`
  - output: `print("args.age=%s" % args.age)` -> `args=Namespace(a=20)`

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [plac](https://github.com/micheles/plac) (a wrapper around `argparse`).

As a bonus it generates neat help instructions - see  below.

#### Example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def main(
    arg: ('Argument with two possible values', 'positional', None, None, ['A', 'B'])
):
    """General help for application"""
    if arg == 'A':
        print("Argument has value A")
    elif arg == 'B':
        print("Argument has value B")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import plac
    plac.call(main)
```

#### Example output:

*No arguments supplied -* `example.py`:

```
usage: example.py [-h] {A,B}
example.py: error: the following arguments are required: arg
```

*Unexpected argument supplied -* `example.py C`:

```
usage: example.py [-h] {A,B}
example.py: error: argument arg: invalid choice: 'C' (choose from 'A', 'B')
```

*Correct argument supplied -* `example.py A` :

```
Argument has value A
```

*Full help menu (generated automatically) -* `example.py -h`:

```
usage: example.py [-h] {A,B}

General help for application

positional arguments:
  {A,B}       Argument with two possible values

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

#### Short explanation:

The name of the argument usually equals the parameter name (`arg`).

The tuple annotation after `arg` parameter has the following meaning:

- Description (`Argument with two possible values`)
- Type of argument - one of 'flag', 'option' or 'positional' (`positional`)
- Abbreviation (`None`)
- Type of argument value - eg. float, string (`None`)
- Restricted set of choices (`['A', 'B']`)

#### Documentation:

To learn more about using [plac](https://github.com/micheles/plac) check out its great documentation:

> [Plac: Parsing the Command Line the Easy Way](https://github.com/micheles/plac/blob/0.9.6/doc/plac.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

New to this, but combining Python with Powershell and using this template, being inspired by an in-depth and great [Python Command Line Arguments – Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-command-line-arguments/#argparse)

There is a lot you can do within the `init_argparse()` and I am covering just the most simple scenario here.

1. `import argparse`
2. use `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` pattern to execute from terminal
3. parse arguments within the `main()` function that has no parameters as all
4. define a `init_argparse()` function

   - create a parser object by calling `argparse.ArgumentParser()`
   - declare one or more argumnent with `parser.add_argument("--<long_param_name>")`
   - return parser
5. parse args by creating an `args` object by calling `parser.parse_args()`
6. define a function proper with `param1`, `param2`, ...
7. call `function_proper` with params being assigned as attributes of an `args` object

   - e.g. `function_proper(param1=args.param1, param2=args.param2)`
8. within a shell call the module with named arguments:

   - e.g. `python foobar.py --param1="foo" --param2=="bar"`

```py
#file: foobar.py
import argparse

def function_proper(param1, param2):
    #CODE...

def init_argparse() -> argparse.ArgumentParser:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--param1")
    parser.add_argument("--param2")
    return parser


def main() -> None:
    parser = init_argparse()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    function_proper(param1=args.param1, param2=args.param2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
>>> python .\foobar.py --param1="foo" --param2=="bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to what others have stated:

I usually like to use the 'dest' parameter to specify a variable name and then use 'globals().update()' to put those variables in the global namespace.

Usage:

```
$ python script.py -i "Hello, World!"
```

Code:

```
...
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', ..., dest='inputted_variable',...)
globals().update(vars(parser.parse_args()))
...
print(inputted_variable) # Prints "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: Internally `argparse` uses `getattr` and `setattr` to access values in  the Namespace.  That way it isn't bothered by oddly formed `dest` values.

Answer (score 3):

I went through all the examples and answers and in a way or another they didn't address my need. So I will list her a scenario that I need more help and I hope this can explain the idea more.

### Initial Problem

I need to develop a tool which is getting a file to process it and it needs some optional configuration file to be used to configure the tool.

so what I need is something like the following

```
mytool.py file.text -config config-file.json
```

### The solution

Here is the solution code

```py
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This example for a tool to process a file and configure the tool using a config file.')
    parser.add_argument('filename', help="Input file either text, image or video")
    # parser.add_argument('config_file', help="a JSON file to load the initial configuration ")
    # parser.add_argument('-c', '--config_file', help="a JSON file to load the initial configuration ", default='configFile.json', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', default='configFile.json', dest='config_file', help="a JSON file to load the initial configuration " )
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', action="store_true", help="Enable the debug mode for logging debug statements." )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    filename = args.filename
    configfile = args.config_file

    print("The file to be processed is", filename)
    print("The config file is", configfile)

    if args.debug:
        print("Debug mode enabled")
    else:
        print("Debug mode disabled")

    print("and all arguments are: ", args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I will show the solution in multiple enhancements to show the idea

#### First Round: List the arguments

List all input as mandatory inputs so second argument will be

```
parser.add_argument('config_file', help="a JSON file to load the initial configuration ")
```

When we get the help command for this tool we find the following outcome

```
(base) > python .\argparser_example.py -h
usage: argparser_example.py [-h] filename config_file

This example for a tool to process a file and configure the tool using a config file.

positional arguments:
  filename     Input file either text, image or video
  config_file  a JSON file to load the initial configuration

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
```

and when I execute it as the following

```
(base) > python .\argparser_example.py filename.txt configfile.json
```

the outcome will be

```
The file to be processed is filename.txt
The config file is configfile.json
and all arguments are:  Namespace(config_file='configfile.json', filename='filename.txt')
```

But the config file should be optional, I removed it from the arguments

```
(base) > python .\argparser_example.py filename.txt
```

The outcome will be is:

```
usage: argparser_example.py [-h] filename config_file
argparser_example.py: error: the following arguments are required: c
```

Which means we have a problem in the tool

#### Second Round : Make it optimal

So to make it optional I modified the program as follows

```py
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', help="a JSON file to load the initial configuration ", default='configFile.json', required=False)
```

The help outcome should be

```
usage: argparser_example.py [-h] [-c CONFIG] filename

This example for a tool to process a file and configure the tool using a config file.

positional arguments:
  filename              Input file either text, image or video

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -c CONFIG, --config CONFIG
                        a JSON file to load the initial configuration
```

so when I execute the program

```
(base) > python .\argparser_example.py filename.txt
```

the outcome will be

```
The file to be processed is filename.txt
The config file is configFile.json
and all arguments are:  Namespace(config_file='configFile.json', filename='filename.txt')
```

with arguments like

```
(base) > python .\argparser_example.py filename.txt --config_file anotherConfig.json
```

The outcome will be

```
The file to be processed is filename.txt
The config file is anotherConfig.json
and all arguments are:  Namespace(config_file='anotherConfig.json', filename='filename.txt')
```

#### Round 3: Enhancements

to change the flag name from `--config_file` to  `--config` while we keep the variable name as is we modify the code to include `dest='config_file'` as the following:

```py
parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', help="a JSON file to load the initial configuration ", default='configFile.json', dest='config_file')
```

and the command will be

```
(base) > python .\argparser_example.py filename.txt --config anotherConfig.json
```

To add the support for having a debug mode flag, we need to add a flag in the arguments to support a boolean debug flag. To implement it i added the following:

```py
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', action="store_true", help="Enable the debug mode for logging debug statements." )
```

the tool command will be:

```
(carnd-term1-38) > python .\argparser_example.py image.jpg -c imageConfig,json --debug
```

the outcome will be

```
The file to be processed is image.jpg
The config file is imageConfig,json
Debug mode enabled
and all arguments are:  Namespace(config_file='imageConfig,json', debug=True, filename='image.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

code:

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-A', default=False, action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-B', default=False, action='store_true')
args=parser.parse_args()
if args.A:
  print('do this')
elif args.B:
  print('do that')
else:
  print('help')
```

running result:

```
$ python3 test.py
help

$ python3 test.py -A
do this

$ python3 test.py -B
do that

$ python3 test.py -C
usage: test.py [-h] [-A] [-B]
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -C
```

As for the original request (if A ....), I would use argv to solve it, not using argparse at all:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv)==2:
  if sys.argv[1] == 'A':
    print('do this')
  elif sys.argv[1] == 'B':
    print('do that')
  else:
    print('help')
else:
  print('help')
```

Answer (score 1):

A really simple way to use argparse and amend the '-h'/ '--help' switches to display your own personal code help instructions is to set the default help to False, you can also add as many additional .add_arguments as you like:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)

parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help',
                help='To run this script please provide two arguments')
parser.parse_args()
```

Run: python test.py -h

Output:

```
usage: test.py [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  To run this script please provide two arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to existing answers, if you are lazy enough, it is possible to use code generation tool called [protoargs](https://github.com/ashlander/protoargs). It generates arguments parser from the configuration. For python it uses **argparse**.

**Configuration with optional A and B**:

```
syntax = "proto2";
message protoargs
{
    optional string A     = 1; // A param description
    optional string B     = 2; // B param description
}//protoargs
```

**Configuration with required A and B**:

```
syntax = "proto2";
message protoargs
{
    required string A     = 1; // A param description
    required string B     = 2; // B param description
}//protoargs
```

**Configuration with positional A and B**:

```
syntax = "proto2";
message protoargs
{
    required string A     = 1; // A param description
    required string B     = 2; // B param description
}//protoargs
message protoargs_links
{
}//protoargs_links
```

Now all you should run is:

```
python ./protoargs.py -i test.proto -o . --py
```

And use it (it is possible to take other examples here):

```
import sys
import test_pa

class ArgsParser:
    program = "test"
    description = "Simple A and B parser test."

    def parse(self, argv):
        self.config = test_pa.parse(self.program, self.description, argv)

    def usage(self):
        return test_pa.usage(self.program, self.description)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgsParser()

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print(parser.usage())
    else:
        parser.parse(sys.argv[1:])

        if parser.config.A:
            print(parser.config.A)

        if parser.config.B:
            print(parser.config.B)
```

If you want more - change configuration, regenerate parser, use an updated parser.config.

**UPD: As mentioned in rules, I must specify that this is my own project**

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not clarified wheather the arguments 'A' and 'B' are positional or optional, I'll make a mix of both.

Positional arguments are required by default. If not giving one will throw 'Few arguments given' which is not the case for the optional arguments going by their name. This program will take a number and return its square by default, if the cube option is used it shall return its cube.

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('number-game')
parser.add_argument(
    "number",
    type=int,
    help="enter a number"
   )
parser.add_argument(
   "-c", "--choice",
   choices=['square','cube'],
   help="choose what you need to do with the number"
)

# all the results will be parsed by the parser and stored in args
args = parser.parse_args()

# if square is selected return the square, same for cube 
if args.c == 'square':
    print("{} is the result".format(args.number**2))
elif args.c == 'cube':
    print("{} is the result".format(args.number**3))
else:
    print("{} is not changed".format(args.number))
```

**usage**

```sh
$python3 script.py 4 -c square
16
```

Here the optional arguments are taking value, if you just wanted to use it like a flag you can too. So by using -s for square and -c for cube we change the behaviour, by adding action = "store_true". It is changed to true only when used.

```py
parser.add_argument(
    "-s", "--square",
    help="returns the square of number",
    action="store_true"
    )
parser.add_argument(
    "-c", "--cube",
    help="returns the cube of number",
    action="store_true"
    )
```

so the conditional block can be changed to,

```py
if args.s:
    print("{} is the result".format(args.number**2))
elif args.c:
    print("{} is the result".format(args.number**3))
else:
    print("{} is not changed".format(args.number))
```

**usage**

```sh
$python3 script.py 4 -c
64
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest answer!

P.S. the one who wrote the document of argparse is foolish

python code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument('--o_dct_fname',type=str)
parser.add_argument('--tp',type=str)
parser.add_argument('--new_res_set',type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
o_dct_fname = args.o_dct_fname
tp = args.tp
new_res_set = args.new_res_set
```

running code

```
python produce_result.py --o_dct_fname o_dct --tp father_child --new_res_set 1
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything new/different than existing answers.