# I'm wanting to perform ridiculously simple string passing using argparse

Tags: argparse

I want to pass a string (could be anything) with the program.

```
python argparsetest.py test_phrase
>>> You typed "test_phrase"
```

Edit: I realise this is a really simple question, I was planning on using argparse as a basis for adding further arguments at a later stage.

Comment: Have you tried the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)? Also, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427101/dead-simple-argparse-example-wanted-1-argument-3-results)

Comment: *"Could anyone give me a hint where to start?"* is not an appropriate question for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) documentation. It has [an example](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#introducing-positional-arguments) implementing this exact scenario.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('test_phrase')
args = parser.parse_args()
print 'You typed "%s"' % args.test_phrase
```

Executing the script:

```
~/tmp/so$ python argparsetext.py example
You typed "example"
~/tmp/so$
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the following as `argparsetest.py` and you're good to go. `argv[n]` returns the `n`th command-line argument.

```
from sys import argv

def main():
    print "You typed " + argv[1]

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend docopts for option parsing. It lets you write the documentation first and generates a dictionary based on that. Maybe better for larger projects, as I am not sure what you are trying to do.

http://docopt.org