# Unable to get the value of a command argument using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to parse the command line arguments in a very simple way:

```
$ python main.py --path /home/me/123
```

or

```
$ python main.py --path=/home/me/123
```

And then:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--path')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

And `args` returns nothings:

```
(Pdb) args
(Pdb) args.path
```

How can I access the value of `--path`?

Comment: This is working for me. just try `print args.path`.

Comment: Also look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427101/dead-simple-argparse-example-wanted-1-argument-3-results.

Answer (score 0):

You can print `args.path` and it will show your line argument. For more details you can check the below link for more details about `argparse`

- [Argparse Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)

You can also use `sys` to parse your command line arguments, such as

```
>>> import sys
>>> path = sys.argv[1]  # sys.argv always start at 1
>>> print path
```

Check the below link for more details.

- [Python Command Line Arguments](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)

Hope it helps.

Comment: For trivial input parameters it is ok, but I would not suggest it for more complex things.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me...

```
>>> args
Namespace(path='/home/me/123')
```

So you can access it via `args.path`