# named argument in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I want to send arguments to script by their name (something like kwargs).
I tried something like this but it's not doing what I want: (let's say it's written in script.py)

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("name")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

and then writing in commant line: script.py name = david

another thing, let's say I have few named argument in argparse If I will send them not in the order they are declared will it still work well?

Comment: This link may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/22045954/1394473

Answer (score 26):

The question as stated contains a bit of a misunderstanding, or I have a big one.

*keyword and **keyword are for passing parameters/stuff to classes/functions/methods INSIDE the python code.

argparse is used to pass arguments/options into the python program from outside/the commandline. So you're not going to get a 1 for 1 replication of it. However argparse is pretty configurable, and depending on how you want to do it you can come close.

If you only want to pass one name, then:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("name")
args = parser.parse_args()

print args
```

will let you:

```
$ ./pytest.py dave
Namespace(name='dave')
```

If you want to set name so you can send other stuff as well:

```
parser.add_argument("-name")
```

Will let you:

```
./pytest.py -name dave
Namespace(name='dave')
```

but notice:

```
 ./pytest.py -name dave -name steve
 Namespace(name='steve')
```

However:

```
parser.add_argument("--name")
```

will let/require:

```
./pytest.py --name dave
Namespace(name='dave')

./pytest.py --name=dave
Namespace(name='dave')
```

and if you:

```
parser.add_argument("--name", nargs="+")

./pytest.py --name dave steve murphy
Namespace(name=['dave', 'steve', 'murphy'])
```

But:

```
 ./pytest.py --name=dave --name=steve --name=murphy      
 Namespace(name=   ['murphy'])
```

(note that that last one is a list with only murphy in it.)

So what you could do is:

```
parser.add_argument("--name")
parser.add_argument("--email")
parser.add_argument("--hair-color")

./pytest.py --name fred --hair-color murphy --email example@example.com
Namespace(email='example@example.com', hair_color='murphy', name='fred')
```

Answer (score 7):

In `argparse`, and earlier command line processers of the same style, there's a distinction between 'optionals' or flagged arguments and positionals.

'optionals' are signaled by a flag string, something like `-f` or `--foo`.  These are similar to the keyword arguments of Python functions, but not identical.  The order does not matter.  With in limits the flags can be joined to the values, e.g. `-f1`, `--foo=astring`.

'positionals' are identified by order, without any identifying name.  These are similar to the `args` of Python functions.  In functions, all positional args have to occur before keyword ones.  With `argparse` 'optionals' can mixed with 'positionals' - with some limits.  It's common to supply all positionals after the optionals, as indicated in the `argparse` usage message.

Look at the examples in the `argparse` documentation.

Periodically we get questions from people who want to circumvent these conventions, for example expecting to use flag without the prefix characters, or to input dictionary like pairs, `foo=test` or `foo:test`.  Some of this is possible, but it takes more work.  And usually for little gain in clarity and usefulness.

I'd suggest passing `script.py name = david` to a script that just displays the `sys.argv` list.  These are the values that `argparse` has to work with.  I expect you will see:

```
['script.py', 'name', '=', 'david']
```

Your shell has split that commandline into separate strings. It is probably easier to do your own parsing of that list than it is to twist `argparse` into a form that will it.

Argparse can easily handle inputs like

```
script.py --name david
script.py --name=david
script.py david
```

Answer (score 0):

Order doesn't matter.

Change your argument to

```
parser.add_argument('-name')
```

Also, what's wrong is your call from command line. It should look like this:

```
python script.py name david
```