# Python commandline parameter not raising error if argument is wrongly used

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, optional-parameters

I have the following Python code that has 1 command line optional parameter (`c`) that has an argument and 2 options (`a` and `b`) that do not have an argument:

```
import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
   inputfile = ''
   outputfile = ''
   try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"abc:",["csvfile="])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print 'Error in usage - a does not require an argument'
      sys.exit(2)
   for opt, arg in opts:
      print "Raw input is: {}" .format(opt)
      if opt in ("-c", "--csvfile"):
         outputfile = arg
         print 'Output file is {}' .format(outputfile)
      elif opt == '-a':
         print 'Alpha'
      elif opt == '-b':
         print 'Beta'
      print 'User choice is {}' .format(opt.lstrip('-'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

When I enter `python readwritestore.py -a` I get:

```
Raw input is: -a
Alpha
User choice is a
```

This is what I was hoping for if the commandline argument is `-a`. However, if I enter `python readwritestore.py -a csvfile_name`, then I get:

```
Raw input is: -a
Alpha
User choice is a
```

This is not what I intended for. In this function, `c` is the only option that rquires an argument. If I enter `a` with an argument,
the code should give the error message that I set up

```
Error in usage - a does not require an argument
```

This does not happen for `a` or `b`. It is allowing the argument to be entered without raising an error.

If the options that do not require an argument are entered with an argument, then I would like it to raise an error. `python readwritestore.py -a text`
and `python readwritestore.py -b text` should raise the error `Error in usage - a does not require an argument`.

Is there a way to specify this? Is `getopt()` the correct way to do this?

**Additional Information:**

I only want `python readwritestore.py -c text` to work with the argument. For the other 2 options, `a` and `b`, the code should raise the error.

Comment: You might want to consider [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), Python's more intuitive module for this.

Comment: I have a lot of issue managing argument for script without a lib. But with [Argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) this is really easy.  I can post an anwser using this lib if you want.

Comment: Was going to suggest the same, if you have no problems changing, give argparse a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking the size of sys.argv (the list of argument supplied when calling the script) can help you checking that :

```
import sys
import getopt


def main(argv):
    inputfile = ''
    outputfile = ''
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "abc:", ["csvfile="])
    for opt, arg in opts:
        print "Raw input is:", opt
        if opt in ("-c", "--csvfile"):
            outputfile = arg
            print 'Output file is ', outputfile
        elif opt == '-a':
            if len(sys.argv)=2:
                print 'Alpha'
            else:
                print "incorect number of argument"
        elif opt == '-b':
            if len(sys.argv)=2:
                print 'Beta'
            else:
                print "incorect number of argument"
        print 'User choice is ', opt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I know it's not what you asked (argparse) but here is how you could do it with argparse :

```
from argparse import *

def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--csvfile', help='do smth with cvsfile')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-a', '--Alpha', help='Alpha', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-b', '--Beta', help='beta smth', action='store_true')
    if args.csvfile:
        print 'Output file is {}' .format(args.csvfile)
    if args.Alpha:
        print 'Alpha'
    if args.Beta:
        print 'Beta'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It will raise an error is to many argument are supplied. (also `python readwritestore.py -h` will display the help just like man in unix)

Comment: That's exactly the mistake I made! Thanks for catching it. But `argparse` seems a lot better. I'll have to look into this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to ask a followup question. `argparse` looks really good - I am having trouble finding beginner's level tutorials for it - is there a good one that can be recommended for this?

Comment: @WR I understand you, the first time you use it it seems messed up. To learn it, i just copy-pasted exemple from there Doc, and tried to test value and tried to understand what appends. here is the tiniest exemple i satrted with : [SO exemple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427101/dead-simple-argparse-example-wanted-1-argument-3-results)

Comment: @WR the thing you have to focus on are  : `action=` and `nargs=`. And at first, don't look into subparser

Comment: Thanks. That will get me going. I seem to have some understanding of `nargs=`...need to really focus on `action=`. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @WR I stumbled upon that today : http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/train-your-python-part-23-argparse-module-0170874/