# Python use commands when running script

Tags: python

I'm writing a script in python and I need to do something like this:

`python myscript.py command1 --commandarg1 --commandarg2`

`python myscript.py --scriptargument1 --scriptargument2 command2 --commandarg1 --commandarg2 --commandarg3`

Is this possible using `argparse`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dead simple argparse example wanted: 1 argument, 3 results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427101/dead-simple-argparse-example-wanted-1-argument-3-results)

Comment: "Is this possible using `argparse`?".  [Yes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).  Argparse calls these `subcommands` (which are parsed by "subparsers")

Comment: @mgilson please add it as an answer, that is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Yes the argparse module is exactly that what you are looking for.

visit this page to get the informations how to work with it:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html