# How to add arguments in a command in Linux

Tags: python, linux

I am making a Linux application which synchronizes the User's Desktop data with the cloud. I made a python executable file **clouddrive** which can launch the application. I copied this file into **/usr/local/bin**. Now, If I type **clouddrive** on the terminal, then it opens the application. But I want to add some arguments to that command. Suppose If user type **clouddrive --logout**, then the user should be logged out. If user type **clouddrive --preferences**, then preferences panel should be opened. I want to know that how can I add these arguments to that command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simple argparse example wanted: 1 argument, 3 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427101/simple-argparse-example-wanted-1-argument-3-results)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 3):

Use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) module.

Example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("echo", help="echo the string you use here")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.echo
```

Result:

```
$ python prog.py -h
usage: prog.py [-h] echo

positional arguments:
  echo        echo the string you use here

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```