# Passing a value to a python variable from batch script

Tags: python

I have the below python script which takes a user input that is eventually used by the program to read a particular file.

I want to execute the python program from batch script and pass the file_name in the batch script. Can someone please help?

```
file_name = input("Input File Name to Compare: ")

path = ("outward\\" + file_name)
```

Comment: Check out the [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427101/simple-argparse-example-wanted-1-argument-3-results)

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
file_name = sys.argv[1]
path = "outward\\" + file_name
```

and you pass it to your script like:

```
$ python script.py filename.ext
```

Answer (score 1):

To run the Python program from the batch script and pass the filename into the batch script, you need to use `sys`, so:

```
import sys
```

`sys.argv` is automatically a list of strings representing arguments on the command line. You can use this as an input for your program. Represents the first command line argument (like a string) given to the script in question.

The lists are indexed by numbers based on zero, so you can get the individual items using the `syntax [0]`. To get the script name, you need to get the first argument after the script for a filename, so:

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
path = "outward\\" + file_name
```

Next you need to pass it to your script like this:

```
$ python your_script.py filename.ext
```

(not to be confused with .ext with .text)

Your complete code for the solution to the question, quite simply, will be:

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
path = "outward\\" + file_name
```

and

```
   $ python your_script.py filename.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `sys.argv` Python function.

The idea would be to get the input from the user in the batch file, then execute the Python program **from the batch file** while passing the user input as a command line argument to the python file. Example:

batchfile.bat

```
@echo off
set /p file="Enter Filename: "

python /path/to/program/pythonprogram.py %file%
```

pythonprogram.py

```
import sys 
 
sys.argv[0] = file_name
path = ("outward\\" + file_name)
```

Now, when you execute the batch file, it will prompt for user input of a filename. Then, it will execute the Python program while passing the filename as a command-line argument to the Python file. Then using the `sys.argv` function you can collect the argument.