# Get two strings by parse one command line argument

Tags: python, csv, parsing, command-line-arguments

I want to turn a command line like this

```
python3 abc.py abc.csv CC
```

into strings `abc.csv` and `CC`

but I'm not sure if I should use the **parse_args()** once or call it twice at the **main()**, as demonstrated below

```
def parse_args( arg ) :
  
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument( "file", help = "path to csv file" )
    return parser.parse_args( arg )


if __name__ == "__main__" :

    path = parse_args( sys.argv [ : - 3 ] )
    
    abv = parse_args( sys.argv [ - 2 : ] )

    func( path, abv )
```

where **func()** take two strings.
Right now it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple argparse example wanted: 1 argument, 3 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427101/simple-argparse-example-wanted-1-argument-3-results)

Comment: Close but I think my problem is more of mixing two different concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parse_args()` will typically be called only once with no arguments:

```py
def parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("file", help="path to csv file")
    parser.add_argument("abv")
    return parser.parse_args()  # same as parse_args(sys.argv[1:])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    func(args.file, args.abv)
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I'm looking for! It works!